# VMotion using iSCSI LUN on OpenFiler

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, openfiler

Does anyone know if it is possible to "share" a LUN on an OpenFiler iSCSI target so I can use VMotion? So far I can't get my second ESX server to connect to the LUN.

Comment: if you just screwing around then no problem, but the openfiler is not an approved storage solution. you can also use nfs to accomplish what you want. Wouldn't recommend either solution though!

Answer (score 2):

Haven't messed with OpenFiler that much, but just because a something says "iSCSI" or "NFS" on it doesn't mean it is necessarily compatible with VMware ESX. VMFS is a clustered file system, and therefore uses locking/reservation features of the iSCSI protocol that are often not available or poorly implemented in many iSCSI implementations (low-end NAS devices for example).

If you're running this setup in production, and not just a test lab, I would strongly suggest finding something from the official VMware hardware compatibility list. This will cost money, but there are some less-expensive devices on there.

We use OpenSolaris storage on an old box in our VMware lab, because it is cheap. We use HP/LeftHand clustered storage in our production VMware cluster. This isn't ideal, but ponying up $3/GB for the test lab didn't make it past accounting.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem, 
follow this: http://www.petri.co.il/connect-vmware-esx-server-iscsi-san-openfiler.htm